# Python Application URL

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, localhost, hosting

I created a Django Python application in localhost and setup virtualenv for running python application. I run this application from terminal and can access with this url- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` . On hosting time (server) how can i access this application using url?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check out this page of the django documentation if you haven't already: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Deployment of a web application is not as easy as running the python development server, that is extremely simpler and is discouraged to be used on a server by the django documentation itself.

On a theoretic point of view, the reason why you can't access remotely the development server is because it binds the server on local only access: to make it accessible from an external computer you need to bind it to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, then you will be able to reach it on example.com:8000 depending on what the server's domain is and what port you choose. To use 0.0.0.0 you call manage.py runserver like this:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

but avoid to do it, and opt for a more robust deployment :)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to deploy your application for the first time, and you want to get a feel of accessing your app from url, try heroku, https://www.heroku.com/

Easy and you don't have to worry about setting up everything.